# Octomap launch with Turtlebot

Tags: octomap, ros-hydro, octomap-server, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are trying to create a 3D map of a room using the octomap_server with the Turtlebot.  Has anyone had any success using octomap_server on Hydro?  Is there anything in our main launch file that seems extremely wrong?   When we run our launch files described below and receive an error:

[octomap_server-19] process has died [pid 3571, exit code -4, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/octomap_server/octomap_server_node /cloud_in:=/camera/depth_registered/points tf_static:=/tf __name:=octomap_server...

We first launch: roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch and then we launch our custom launch file being:

```
<launch>

<include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/3dsensor.launch">
    <arg name="scan_topic" value="/scan" />
</include>

<node pkg="octomap_server" type="octomap_server_node" name="octomap_server">

                <param name="resolution" value="0.05" />

                <!-- fixed map frame (set to 'map' if SLAM or localization running) -->
                <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="/odom" />

                <!-- maximum range to integrate (speedup!) -->
                <param name="sensor_model/max_range" value="5.0" />

                <!-- data source to integrate (PointCloud2) -->
                <remap from="/cloud_in" to="/camera/depth_registered/points" />

                <remap from="tf_static" to="/tf" />

</node>

</launch>
```

Before we had this error we used rviz.
Fixed frame in rviz as: /odom
PointCloud2 topic: /octomap_point_cloud_centers
Note:unable to get anything but worked with the topic: /camera/depth_registered/points

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143746/octomap-launch-with-turtlebot/) by [rexcummings](https://answers.ros.org/users/13781/rexcummings/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your launch file should work. I was able to do 3D mapping using the sample launch file in the octomap_server. Try to set the Target frame as:/camera_depth_frame to convert the camera_depth_optical_frame of kinect to camera_depth_frame.

Also if you are not getting the point cloud. Add the octomap_point_cloud when choosing the pointcloud2.

The odometry of turtlebot is very poor. So, do not expect to get very pretty and accurate 3D maps.

---

Originally posted by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) with karma: 340 on 2014-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0